# Private Sub Worksheet_Change VBA code merging issue

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am using the below codes to change the "Sheet2" "D2" value as per the value in "Sheet1" "B2" and VICE VERSA too. But they are not working together. If I use them separately then both coding is working perfectly. How can I correct them to perform together?

"Sheet1"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "Included": Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = Target.Value
    Case Is = "Excluded": Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = Target.Value
    End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

"Sheet2"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "Included": Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = Target.Value
    Case Is = "Excluded": Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = Target.Value
    End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". Are these events meant to run on changes to those sheets or run on any change on either sheet?

Comment: If in sheet1 in "B2" cell I select "Included" then in sheet2 "D2" cell will change as per the selection in the "Sheet1" and show included.
If in sheet2 in "D2" cell I select "Excluded" then in sheet1 "B2" cell value will change as per sheet2 selection and show excluded in "B2" cell in sheet1

Comment: Then there is nothing that should be combined. These are two seperate events happening on seperate sheets. These two subs need to each be in the code module for the sheet that they are monitoring, not together.

Comment: ...but they will keep triggering each other unless you use `Application.EnableEvents = False` before updating the other sheet.  Don't forget to re-enable events after the update.

Comment: could you please tell me the correct format to perform these codes?

Answer (score 0):

From comments above:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, v
    
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2"))
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        v = Target.Value
        If v = "Included" Or v = "Excluded" Then
            On Error GoTo haveError           'set up error handling
            Application.EnableEvents = False  'disable events
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2") = v
            Application.EnableEvents = True   're-enable events
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub 'normal exit
    
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure events not left turned off
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Its not working value in sheet2 is not changing as per the selection in sheet1

Comment: Working for me - you will need another copy of this in the sheet2 code module, with the appropriate adjustments.